# React.js output not shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am very new to React.js and trying hands on by following some tutorials and doing exactly what i am doing in index.js but it does not show any output of my code.

I install React and create by using these two commands

**npm install -g create-react-app**

**create-react-app helloworld**

App created and do the following code in the **Index.js** file only without interfering in any other file, But **H1** is not showing on screen. 
Whats the issue, am i doing something wrong?

Here is my code

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class worker extends React.Component{
    render()
    {
        console.log("hello");
        return(
            <h1> hello farrukh </h1>

        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(< worker /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @karthick Its a premade template by react , as i said i dont event touch any other file other then index.js

Comment: are you running this with `npm start`?  are you sure you saved your index.js file?

Comment: use i am running it with npm start and yes i am saving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

All you need to do is rename 'worker' to 'Worker' and it will work.